# FastAPI web service exits with Error Code 139 on AWS ECS and ECR Scan fails with UnsupportedImageError

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github-actions, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

We have a web service written in FastAPI (python 3.8) and we use GitHub Actions and AWS. In CI we build a Docker image, push it to AWS ECR, and then update the ECS task definition and ECS service. This process was working fine until recently (like yesterday or today), when we started encountering an issue where the Docker image within the ECS service exits with the error code "Exited (139)".

The Docker container logs only show the following lines before exiting:

```
INFO: Started server process [1]
INFO: Waiting for application startup..
```

Additionally, we've noticed that ECR can no longer run a scan on the new images. The scan returns the following error: "UnsupportedImageError: The operating system 'debian' version '12' is not supported." We don't use debian at all.

We haven't made any changes to our code recently. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Any pointers on what could be causing these errors and how to fix them would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "We don't use debian at all." What do you use then? What is the `FROM` line in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @MarkB FROM python3.8. Maybe debian here, yes

Comment: will try `FROM python:3.8.17-bullseye`